# Carbonを使用した`今日以降‘の設定

Tags: php, laravel

carbonで今日以降のひづけであればtrue、それ以外はfalseで返すように設定したい
今日は：`$date->isToday();`
未来は：`$date->isFuture();`

この二つを合わせたような、今日以降、にするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

[参考](https://qiita.com/yudsuzuk/items/ff894bd0b76d4657741d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

両者のどちらかは`true` = OR を取るのではだめでしょうか。

```
if( $dt->isToday() || $dt->isFuture() ) {
    ...
}
```